# Prove that there exist two infinite sequences that simultaneously satisfies all these conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality

Prove that there exist two infinite sequences $\langle a_n\rangle_{n\geq 1}$ and $\langle b_n\rangle_{n\geq 1}$ of positive integers such that the following conditions hold simultaneously:

$$1 < a_1 < a_2 < \dots \tag1$$

$$a_n < b_n < a^2_n  \ \forall \  n\geq 1 \tag2$$

$$a_n - 1|b_n-1 \ \forall \ n \geq 1 \tag3$$

$$a_n^2 - 1|b_n^2 - 1\ \forall \ n \geq 1 \tag4$$

I began by trying two integers $a, b$ that satisfied all the above conditions:

$$b-1 = k(a-1) \implies b = k(a-1) + 1$$

$$b^2 - 1 = l(a^2 - 1)$$

$$\implies [k(a-1)+1]^2 - 1 = l(a^2 - 1)$$

$$=k^2(a-1)^2 + 1 + 2k(a-1) - 1 = l(a^2 - 1)$$

$$k^2a^2 + k^2 - 2k^2a + 2ka - 2k = la^2 - l$$

$$\implies (k^2 - l)a^2 = 2k^2a + 2k -2ka - k^2 - l$$

This wasn't helpful in solving the problem. What do I do from here?

Answer (score 1):

You want $b_n=k(a_n-1)+1$, where $1<k \leq a_n$. Also you want $$(a_n-1)(a_n+1)=a_n^2-1 \mid b_n^2-1=(b_n-1)(b_n+1)=k(a_n-1)(k(a_n-1)+2)$$

$$a_n+1 \mid k(k(a_n-1)+2)$$

$$a_n+1 \mid k^2(a_n+1)-k(k(a_n-1)+2)=2k(k-1)$$

Recall that we have freedom to choose $a_n$. So just let

$$k=n+1$$
$$a_n=2k(k-1)-1=2(n+1)^2-2(n+1)-1=2n^2+2n-1$$
$$b_n=k(a_n-1)+1=(n+1)(2n^2+2n-2)+1=2n^3+4n^2-1$$

You can check that these satisfy the given conditions.

Comment: How did you say that $1<k\leq a$?

Comment: You want $a<b<a^2$. You have $b=k(a-1)+1$. So $a<k(a-1)+1<a^2$, giving $1<k \leq a$.